# How do I build a Layout with a button below a Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I build a Search layout with a Text Edit to enter keywords, List View to show result of searching, and a Button "add contact".
I want to build this layout with conditions here:
First, if the i set visibility of List View is GONE (when i start Activity and i have not use search operation yet), i want to display Button "add contact" bellow the Text Edit. 
Next, when i use search operation and receive result, i want to display List View bellow the Text Edit and the Button "add contact" will be moved to the Bottom of layout.
Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topcontrolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent" >

            <Button //This is button Search
                android:id="@+id/magnifier"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_button" /> 

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_key_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/magnifier"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:hint="@string/contactadd3"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" >
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent" >
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"

                >
            </ListView>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegi"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
               android:layout_bellow="@+id/listView1"
                android:background="@drawable/registerbutton"
                android:text="@string/contactadd2"
                android:textColor="#FAFAFA" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

My problems is: It's ok when I start activity, the button btnRegi below the EditText. but when i receive the result and set to List View, the List View will show fill the layout and the button btnRegi disappear.

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my bad english, hope you guys can see my problem. Thanks

Comment: `android:layout_bellow="@+id/listView1"` typo error here is `below` not `bellow`. You can use a single Relative Layout for this

Comment: I'm sorry, this's my mistake, cause i edit in this post.

Answer (score 0):

add a button to the bottom of the list view is not good way to control the list view. Please try to use by adding or bottomview headerview in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I would remove the second relative layout, so that the `LinearLayout` will
have 3 elements:

- Your search button / text field
- The `listView`
- The bottom button.

Add layout_weight at 1 for the `ListView` so that I will use all the vertical space.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topcontrolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent" >

        <Button //This is button Search
            android:id="@+id/magnifier"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_button" /> 

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_key_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/contactadd3"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:layout_bellow="@+id/listView1"
        android:background="@drawable/registerbutton"
        android:text="@string/contactadd2"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this one can help you
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topcontrolbar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/magnifier"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_key_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/magnifier"
            android:hint="contact"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_bellow="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA" />

</LinearLayout>
```